# Disable resizing both tiled windows (left and right)

Tags: linux, kde, window-manager, manjaro, kde-plasma-5

This might be hard to explain, please bear with me.

**TLDR:**
How can I disable the link between two tiled windows when resizing horizontally? So only

**Situation:**

- I have two windows (let's say Firefox and a Terminal).
- I have tiled Firefox to the left (Meta+Left) and the Terminal tiled to the right (Meta+Right).
- Previously, I could resize Firefox without changing anything to the other windows.

Some of the recent Manjaro updates introduced a KDE Plasma feature that kind of changes the tiling *center line*, resizing **all tiled windows**, instead of resizing just that active window.

This has a nasty (imho) side effect that newly tiled windows also tile into that space, instead of just to the equal left or right half of the screen (50%).

So for example, if I drag the center point almost all the way to the right, the terminal will be very narrow while Firefox is very wide. However, if I tile a new Firefox window to the right, it also is that narrow.

To overrule this, I have to unsnap the window from the tiling position (eg. by resizing it vertically first) before I can freely resize it horizontally.

**Question:**

- How do I disable it? (Resizing both windows. Or, how can I resize just that single window, not influencing the other windows?)

**Bonus questions:**

- What is this feature called?
- Can I also toggle it with a keyboard shortcut?

**Extra info:**

- I'm running KDE Plasma 5.27.7
- on Manjaro-KDE 23.0.0
- with the Wayland display server.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried searching the KDE changelogs and announcements but I didn't find this particular feature. I don't think it's the new tiling system announced in [version 5.27.0](https://kde.org/announcements/plasma/5/5.27.0/) (which is still very buggy), although the effect of resizing is the same.

I've googled for 'kde plasma resize tiled windows' and 'kwin disable center snap' etc. I've looked at the options in the settings, several times. Not knowing what I was exactly looking for, I was unable to find the setting resulting in finally opening this question.